Prisma find record where relation field matches exact list of Ids
I am building a chat feature in my app and using Prisma ORM. I have a "conversation" model that looks like this:
model Conversation {
    id           String     @id              @default(uuid())
    players      Player[]
    messages     Message[]
    createdAt    DateTime   @default(now())
    updatedAt    DateTime   @updatedAt
    @@map("conversations")
}

A conversation can be related to many players. Using a list of playerIds, I would like to find a conversation that contains exactly this list of playerIds.
If found, I will reuse this conversation and prevent a duplicate conversation from being created that contains the exact the same players.
I tried using this query to filter players by a list of Ids, but this returns all conversation where any conversation contains these ids.
const conversations = await prisma.conversation.findMany({
    select: {
      players: {
        where: {
          id: { in: listOfIds }
        },
      }
    }
})

What I need is to find exactly 1 record where the list of players related to this covnersation match a list of playerIds.

Try this approach
const conversations = await prisma.conversation.findMany({
  where: {
    players: {
      every: { id: { in: listOfIds } }
    },
  },
  select: {
    // Include necessary fields here
  },
});


Yes, this worked! I didn't realize you should include a relation field in the "where" query.
FYI, In the end I used "findFirst" instead of "findMany".
Thank you!

While the current accepted answer answers the question of how to query, there's a better way to handle "prevent creating duplicate records" which is more idiomatic to relation databases.
Instead of first doing a query and then using app logic for separate action paths, you can use UPSERT to achieve this in one statement:
const conversation = await prisma.conversation.upsert({
  where: {
    players: {
      every: { id: { in: listOfIds } }
    },
  },
  create: {
    // Fields in case this is a new record
  },
  update: {
    // Fields in case this is an update
  },
});


Not all DB engines support UPSERT (you can read more about that e.g. here, but fortunately Prisma has built in support for upsert statements.
